# Background-Image in <img> element

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me to find my Problem ?
I have a `<img />` and will give him a background-image within a `<a>` tag.

Here is my example:

```
<img border="0" style="display:block; width:20px; height:20px; background-color:red; padding:9px; background:url(\'./images/system/button/close/close.png)\' no-repeat" />
```

Background-Color didn't work to.. :-( My Example is a JavaScript String, thats the reason why I'm escaping the URL

Thank's for help :-)

Comment: Why are you escaping the quotes? Are you sure about the leading `.` in the URL?

Comment: unless im extremely confused, why are you adjusting the BG of an img tag without making use of its SRC attribute? and the leading `./` in the url is just a relative path i think

Comment: Why not use the src attribute? Why you need to use background-image?

Comment: you escape the quote after the closing ) ^^

Comment: After reading the question and answers, i funny thought came to my mind : You're fired!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you dont even need the quote marks.

```
background:url(./images/system/button/close/close.png)
```

use a div if you can

```
<div style="height:20px; width:20px; padding:9px; background:url(./images/system/button/close/close.png) no-repeat red"></div>
```

Comment: please note, divs are by default displayed as block image are inline

Comment: Also noteworthy is that your background-color is not working because you're overruling it farther on.  Either do `background: red url(...)` or use `background-image` instead.

Comment: Why 'use a div if you can'? Surely an image element makes more semantic sense if the purpose of the element is to display an image

Answer (score 3):

You are escaping your quote marks and have transposed the second quote mark and bracket.

In CSS:

```
url('foo')   /* is technically fine but broken on IE/Mac */
url(foo)     /* is fine */
url('foo)'   /* is not fine */
url(\'foo\') /* is not fine */
```

And as Ross points out in a comment, your `src` attribute is missing. I imagine that setting a background-image on an image with a translucent background will work, but if you don't have a content image, don't use an `<img>` element (and don't hide any content images you do have in in `background-image` properties).

Comment: Which element is qualified for using a Image with background inside a <a> tag ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand why you are escaping the quotes.

```
 <img border="0" style="display:block; width:20px; height:20px; background-color:red; padding:9px; background:url('./images/system/button/close/close.png') no-repeat" />
```

Does that work?

And are you sure about the . in the URL?

Comment: Because it's a JavaScript String

Answer (score 1):

`background-color:red;` is being superseded by `background:`.

Combine your backgrounds. You can then refine it further by removing the quotes in the URL() of the background and the period from the URL. if it is relative to the location of the page it is on just remove the backslash.

`<img border="0" style="display:block; width:20px; height:20px; padding:9px; background:#F00 url(images/system/button/close/close.png) no-repeat" />`

Last if you need to have an `alt` attribute its contents will show up since there is no source. Use a transparent image if you add the `alt`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even if it's weird to use the `<img/>` tag for this. (it's not its purpose, use `src` or a `div` with background...)

[Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Chouchen/eHv2g/), it's working