# background-image css does not show in img tag

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The responsive image in my bootstrap html does not show:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <img class="myimg img-responsive"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.myimg {
    background-image: url("http://images.wikia.com/worldlanguages/images/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png");
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8mwk7vfh/3/)

`<img src="...">` will work, but I need to define the image in css.

[This similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967344/background-image-in-img-element) suggests using `<div>` and removing the quotes in `url()`, but this did not help.

Why does it not show?

Comment: Height `100%` ... 100% of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set height to all of the parents, and you need `background-size: cover`

([Demo](http://jsbin.com/salinumila/1/))

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
}
.row,
.col-sm-12 {
    height: 100%;
}
.myimg {
    background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/200/200");
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.myimg2 {
    background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/200/200");
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.myimg3 {
    background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/200/200");
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

If you would like to responsively change the background image, you can do it like so.

([Demo](http://jsbin.com/yutudakoko/1/))

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
}
.row,
.col-sm-12 {
    height: 100%;
}
.myimg, .myimg2, .myimg3 {
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .myimg {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/500/500/cats");
  }
  .myimg2 {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/500/500/business");
  }
  .myimg3 {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/500/500/transportation");
  }
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .myimg, .myimg2, .myimg3 {
  .myimg {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/750/750/cats");
  }
  .myimg2 {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/750/750/business");
  }
  .myimg3 {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/750/750/transportation");
  }
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .myimg {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/1000/1000/cats");
  }
  .myimg2 {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/1000/1000/business");
  }
  .myimg3 {
      background-image: url("//lorempixel.com/1000/1000/transportation");
  }
}
```

Comment: It was not me, but in this case, there is not a src set on the img. So the reason why the background is not shown is not the actual image over the background

Comment: Is there a way to make it responsive similar to bootstrap's `img-responsive`? Adding `height: auto`, `max-width:100%` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the image src via css. You gotta turn the img into a block and set the proper width / height to show the background. However, it sounds little strange for me. You should do it on a div:

```
<div class="myimg">        
</div>


.myimg {
   width: 100px; // change to your background width
   height: 100px // change to your background height
   background: url('path/to/img');
}
```

Comment: How would I make the image responsive if I hardcode the width and height?

Comment: Why do you need to use the img as a background?

Comment: I'm trying to swap different images based on screen size. Larger screens will load larger images, smaller screens load smaller images. I would like to do this only with css though, and I thought I could get away using `@media` and setting different background images.

Comment: use background-size: cover, as  humble suggested.